# EXCEL: Attachments.Add for Individual Sheets

Tags: excel

I have a code that I've been using forever to automatically email a workbook via a commandbutton click. I tried to reformat this code to send 2 individual sheets (named: Pass, Pass Screenshot) from the workbook, but I can't get it to work. The sheets won't be active when the email is sent. This is the code I've been using, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
Sub SendEmail()
ThisWorkbook.Save
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.to = "my email"
.Subject = "my subject" & Date
.Attachments.Add '???

.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So normally you would have `.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook`, are you against creating a new workbook with just the two sheets you want to send?

Comment: The `Attachments.Add` method takes a file path argument, you can't reconfigure that to send a worksheet (or array of worksheet) object. What you can do is export those two sheets in to a new/temporary file, send as attachment, and then remove/kill the temporary file which is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Attachments.Add` method takes a file path argument, you can't reconfigure that to send a worksheet (or array of worksheet) object. What you can do is export those two sheets in to a new/temporary file, send as attachment, and then remove/kill the temporary file which is no longer needed.

```
Sub SendEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim tempWB as Workbook
Dim tempFile as String
Dim wb as Workbook

tempFile = Environ("Temp") & "\sheets_copy.xlsx"

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Save
' The Sheets.Copy method will create a new workbook containing the copied sheets
wb.Sheets(Array("Pass", "Pass Screenshot")).Copy 
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

' ensure no temp wb already exists
' this can technically still fail if the file is open/locked
If Len(Dir(tempFile)) <> 0 Then
    Kill tempFile
End If
' Save & close the tempFile
tempWB.SaveAs tempFile
tempWB.Close

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.to = "my email"
.Subject = "my subject" & Date
.Attachments.Add tempFile '## Add your attachment here
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!! Great info. I'm relatively new to VBA and I love learning new things here. Thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: Is there a way to call the sheets if they're hidden?

Comment: Unhide them using `wb.Sheets(Array("Pass", "Pass Screenshot")).Visible = xlSheetVisible` and then you can hide them using `xlSheetHidden` when you're done copying them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: I ended up using a boolean code to hide/unhide the sheets: Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = True